# What is the best way to get information from DB?

Tags: mysql

Which query is better to get data form more than two tables by id field?  use one joins on one query or many select statements?

I want to get the  run time optimal solution.

For example:

I have "tasks" table that include foreign keys fields,
like: statustask (from statustasks table), taskurgency (from taskurgency table)
whate is the best way to get the "tasks" list object form DB:

1. with joins:

   ```
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks "
               + "INNER JOIN statustask_in_language ON tasks.status=statustask_in_language.statustask_id "
               + "INNER JOIN statustasks ON tasks.status=statustasks.id "
               + "INNER JOIN taskurgency_in_language ON tasks.urgency=taskurgency_in_language.taskurgency_id "
               + "INNER JOIN taskurgency ON tasks.urgency=taskurgency.id ";
       List<task> listUsers = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<task>() {

           @Override
           public task mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
               task t = new task();
               tabelsTemplate status=new tabelsTemplate();
               tabelsTemplate urgency=new tabelsTemplate();
                   t.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                   t.setDate(rs.getTimestamp("date"));
                   t.setTargetDate(rs.getTimestamp("targetDate"));
                  t.setSubject(rs.getString("subject"));
                   t.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                  t.setAdminId(rs.getString("adminId"));
                  t.setOpenedBy(rs.getString("openedBy"));

                  status.setId(rs.getString("status"));
                  status.setInCurrentLanguage(rs.getString("statustask_in_language.description"));
                  status.setDescription(rs.getString("desc"));
                  t.setStatusObj(status);

                   urgency.setId(rs.getString("urgency"));
                   urgency.setInCurrentLanguage(rs.getString("taskurgency_in_language.description"));
                   urgency.setDescription(rs.getString("descUrgency"));
                   t.setUrgencyObj(urgency);

               return t;
   ```
2. or use one join and select statments for each foreign key to set the object.
   note: In Task object the  foreign keys are objects (not Ids).

thank you!

Comment: MySql <> Sql Server....

Comment: ? what is it mean?

Comment: MySql is not Sql Server. Those are two different products.

Comment: ok thank you, got your note! do you have any answer to my question?

Comment: Usually, it's recommended to make as little roundtrips between the application and the database as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question, and can't be correctly answered with out the proper information like an example.

Every thing depends on which information you want, and what you want to do with it.

If you are required to get data from multiple tables, `JOINS` is the way to go, since it's the easiest way to connect data to each other without actually needing to do some unnecessary logic.

In most cases - `JOIN` will be the correct way, but then again, there are cases where the logic to align the data with `PHP` for example will be hard , and separate queries can be easier to use.